# Quiz modules for Drupal

Tags: drupal, module, content-management-system

does anybody know about an alternative for Quiz modules in Drupal? I need very simple Quiz functionality. My main problem is that the Questions module inside the Quiz module isn't compatible with PHP 5.1.x, and I need some kind of Quiz module compatible with it (almost all modules usually are). I just need something that tells the correct answer for a question in the end. Thank you!

Comment: I have found that Quiz 3.5 pack allows me to create Multiple choice questions without the Quiz Question module. Quiz question is the one requiring PHP 5.2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform)? With it you could place question & answer entry fields on one page, put a pagebreak and answer on the next, etc...

Comment: Yes, I did look at it, but does it allow me to select a right answer and send the user a feedback based on that right/wrong answer? All I could think of is telling the right answer on the second page (after form submit), but the system would never have the information "you were right/wrong" to send to the user. The only information I could use on the answer page is "the correct answer is ... If you answered thatm congrats..."

Comment: actually as far as I understand you can set up conditional pagebreaks, so if condition 1 is met go to, else..

Comment: Hum... Interesting. I will have a look at that. Thank you!